# como puedo solucionar el siguiente codigo

Tags: java

```
/**
* Calcula la duración promedio de las películas del pasajero.
* @return Duración promedio de las películas del pasajero; 0 en caso que el pasajero no tenga películas
*/

    public int calcularDuracionPromedioPeliculas(int duracionPromedioPeliculas) {
        for (Pelicula pelicula :peliculas) {
            if(darDuracionTotalPeliculas()>0) {
                
                
        }else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return duracionPromedioPeliculas;
    }
```

ese es el codigo que tengo implementado pero al ejecutarlo me salen estos errores

**estos son los errores que me salen**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: listo ya agregue los errores no me habia cargado la foto

Comment: Hiciste bien en poner el código como texto, pero los mensajes de error también sería bueno que estén como texto. Aca se dan razones por las que el código y el mensaje de error van como texto siempre [Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes… ¿cómo sensibilizar a los usuarios de ese principio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu)

Comment: Algo que podes hacer es ponerlo en forma de imagen Y como texto.

Answer (score 0):

en el error dice pasActual.calcularDuracionPromedioPeliculas(), sin embargo tu has declarado el método calcularDuracionPromedioPeliculas para que acepte un paremetro de entrada (int).
Por eso dice que difiere en longitud la lista de argumentos de ese método.